# Wordpress проект и репозиторий. Как настроить совместную разработку?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mysql

Имеется wordpress сайт, репозиторий BitBucket, база данных сайта. Как реализовать совместную разработку?

Перед этим я пытался сливать базу данных на хостинг и настраивать подключение к ней удалённо с локальной машины. Но на одно соединение уходит секунд пять.

Неужели для БД прийдется создавать отдельный репозиторий?

Как быть, что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Под БД не заводятся репозитории. Сохраняется только структура БД с помощью миграций, этим полностью занимается вордпресс. При необходимости перекидываются sql-дампы, но они никогда не идут в репозиторий.